# Does Page File size affect Gaming performance?

Tags: windows-10, performance, gaming, virtual-memory, pagefile

Does changing the Page File size affect gaming performance?  If so, how big of an impact is it & what changes result in better performance?

I'm tweaking Windows to maximize gaming performance. I realize my PC is limited due to a low-end gpu & relatively weak processor, however I still would like to optimize as many settings as I can & was curious about the Paging File but found mixed answers online.

Specs- 
Intel Core i5 6th Gen 6200U (2.30 GHz)
8 GB RAM
1 TB HDD
2 GB NVIDIA GeForce 940M

Comment: I'm voting to close this since per the wording "***the best setting***"  seems too opinion based rather than factual. I'm not sure if I'm cool or not, but this is my thought after reading the question. Feel free to [edit] and reword to make less of a question looking for an opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it was possible to gain performance benefits by micro-managing the Pagefile in previous versions of Windows, it has been unnecessary to do this really since Windows 7.

Especially now with faster and larger hard drives, there are fewer reasons than ever to self-manage the Pagefile.

The only real reason is if your OS drive is too small and you have way too much RAM, which is a rare combination.

For best performance on the average computer running Windows 10, allow Windows to manage the Pagefile.

Comment: I currently have it set to default (auto managed by win) but based on your answer it seems like it is rather unnecessary altogether nowadays - what if I simply turn it off? Does it really matter?

Comment: @DrewB I hope that wasn't what you read, because it wasn't what I wrote. Yes, the page file is necessary and turning it off decreases performance. There are other questions on SU that deal with that topic. Leave it turned on and let Windows manage it.

Comment: Ok sorry for misreading that.  Will do.